# Validate if a reference field is empty not working in moongose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My problem is that options field in SchemaA is not validating if it's empty even if, put the required attribute.

Here is an example of my model

```
const schemaA = new Schema({
       title:{
           type: String,
           required: [true,'this field is required']
       },
       options: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'SchemaB',
        default: undefined,
        required: [true, "cant be empty"]
       }]
})


const schemaB = new Schema({
   title:{
       type: String,
       required: [true,'this field is required']
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the schemaA option fields to this.

```
const schemaA = new Schema({
       title:{
           type: String,
           required: [true,'this field is required']
       },
       options: {
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'SchemaB',
        default: undefined,
        required: [true, "cant be empty"]
       }
})
```